# Why is this react form submitting two times

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a form made with reactjs and a restapi on express to which I'm sending post request from the Confirm page. The main question is why this form is submitting two times? And also it is submitting when I'm pressing next from previous page and not when I'm pressing the submit button on the confirm page. I have tried to change in UserForm in case 4 from this "formHandler={this.formHandler(this.state.valuesToSubmit)}" to this "formHandler={this.formHandler}" but like that it isn't making the request at all. Please help!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import StepOne from './StepOne';
import SocilaProfiles from './SocialProfiles'
import PersonalDetails from './PersonalDetails';
import Confirm from './Confirm';
import Success from './Success';
import axios from 'axios';

export class UserForm extends Component {
    state = {
        step: 1,
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: '',
        twitter: '',
        facebook: '',
        googlePlus: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        phone: '',
        adress: ''
    }

    // Proceed to next step
    nextStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            step: step + 1
        });
    }

    // Go back to prev step
    prevStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            step: step - 1
        });
    }

    // Handle fields change
    handleChange = input => e => {
        this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
    }

    // MAKING POST REQUEST TO THE API
    formHandler = () => {
        const valuesToSubmit = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
            confirmPassword: this.state.confirmPassword,
            twitter: this.state.twitter,
            facebook: this.state.facebook,
            googlePlus: this.state.googlePlus,
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
            phone: this.state.phone,
            adress: this.state.adress
        }
        console.log('Form:')
        console.log(valuesToSubmit)
        axios.post('http://localhost:9000/api', valuesToSubmit)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                //Perform action based on response
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                //Perform action based on error
            });
    }


    render() {
        const { step } = this.state;
        const { email, password, confirmPassword, twitter, facebook, googlePlus, firstName, lastName, phone, adress } = this.state;
        const values = { email, password, confirmPassword, twitter, facebook, googlePlus, firstName, lastName, phone, adress };

        switch (step) {
            case 1:
                return (
                    <StepOne
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        values={values}
                    />
                )
            case 2:
                return (
                    <SocilaProfiles
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        values={values}
                        prevStep={this.prevStep}
                    />
                )
            case 3:
                return (
                    <PersonalDetails
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        prevStep={this.prevStep}
                        values={values}
                    />
                )
            case 4:
                return (
                    <Confirm
                        nextStep={this.nextStep}
                        prevStep={this.prevStep}
                        values={values}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        formHandler={this.formHandler(this.state.valuesToSubmit)}
                    />
                )
            case 5:
                return <Success />
                
        }
    }
}

export default UserForm;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../index.css';

export class Confirm extends Component {
    continue = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // PROCESS FORM -> SEND DATA TO API(EXPRESS)
        this.props.nextStep();
    }

    submit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.formHandler();
    }

    back = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
    }

    render() {
        const { values: { email, password, confirmPassword, twitter, facebook, googlePlus, firstName, lastName, phone, adress }} = this.props;

        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.submit} className="msform">

                <fieldset>
                    <h2 className="fs-title"> Confirm Details </h2>
                    <hr/>
                    <ul className="theList">
                        <li> <strong>Email:</strong> {email} </li>
                        <li> <strong>Twitter:</strong> {twitter} </li>
                        <li> <strong>Facebook:</strong> {facebook} </li>
                        <li> <strong>Google Plus:</strong> {googlePlus} </li>
                        <li> <strong>First Name:</strong> {firstName} </li>
                        <li> <strong>Last Name:</strong> {lastName} </li>
                        <li> <strong>Phone:</strong> {phone} </li>
                        <li> <strong>Adress:</strong> {adress}</li>
                    </ul>
                    <input onClick={this.back} type="button" className="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
                    <input onClick={this.continue} type="button" name="submit" className="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        );
    }
}


export default Confirm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow notation of the function as the function like, This will remove submition of the form on load

```js
 <Confirm
    nextStep={this.nextStep}
    prevStep={this.prevStep}
    values={values}
    handleChange={this.handleChange}
    formHandler={() => this.formHandler(this.state.valuesToSubmit)}
    />
```

Comment: formHandler={() => { this.formHandler(this.state.valuesToSubmit) }} not working

Answer (score 0):

One problem in here is that you have the buttons declared as , this inputs without proper configuration both will work as submit buttons, I suggest you to change them to . The `button` element has a property called type, and it could be `button`, `reset` or `submit`.

Change this:

```
<input onClick={this.back} type="button" className="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
<input onClick={this.continue} type="button" name="submit" className="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
```

To this:

```
<button onClick={this.back} type="button" className="previous action-button">Previous</button>
<button onClick={this.continue} type="submit" name="submit" className="submit action-button">Submit</button>
```

And another problem is that you are calling your function when the component is loading in this line:

```
<Confirm
  nextStep={this.nextStep}
  prevStep={this.prevStep}
  values={values}
  handleChange={this.handleChange}
  formHandler={this.formHandler(this.state.valuesToSubmit)} <<<<<<<<<<
/>
```

You should wrap that formHandler in an anonymous function to prevent it to being called on rendering. Just like

```
<Confirm
  nextStep={this.nextStep}
  prevStep={this.prevStep}
  values={values}
  handleChange={this.handleChange}
  formHandler={() => { this.formHandler(this.state.valuesToSubmit) }}
/>
```

Comment: formHandler={() => { this.formHandler(this.state.valuesToSubmit) }} not working

Comment: Did you check if you are getting the data from 'this.state.valuesToSubmit'?

Comment: With console.log(valuesToSubmit) when I have only {this.formHandler(this.valuesToSubmit} it's showing me two times what's in it

Comment: Yes, but having that function like that is not adequate. You should not be doing a line calling to a function inside an event. I was checking your code and it's not even necessary to pass this.state.valuesToSubmit, because your formHandler is not receiving arguments. Please try to share a sandbox to see this clearly

Comment: then I have to put an input as argument and instead of valuesToSubmit use handleChange ?